# macOS Mojave Command line: How to mount drive but NOT EFI and hidden partitions

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, mojave, external-disk, mount

If I connect a external GUID-Formated Mac Drive, the Finder does mount all partitions except the "hidden" ones EFI and if existing "Recovery HD".
That's fine so far.

If I unmount the disk in the command line with "diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3" it will be unmounted.
Also fine.
But if I then do the opposite with "diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk3", this command will not only mount the relevant data partitions but as well the "EFI" partition and if existing also the "Recovery HD" partition.

As it looks there is no command which behaves like the Finder, I have to extract the disk informations with the diskutility command.
Right now, with `diskutil list $(diskutil list | grep 'external' | awk '{print $1}')` I get the following output.

`/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Server SSD Clone        127.5 GB   disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk3s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Server HDD clone       1000.0 GB   disk3s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Free Space              100.0 GB   disk3s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS Backup                  771.6 GB   disk3s6`

Now I search string manipulations to extract the "NAME" and "IDENTIFIER" information based on filtering out the "TYPE" and "IDENTIFIER" information and exclude the "TYPE" "EFI" and "Apple_Boot".

In the end I should get something like

```
Repeat until last partition
  Part_NAME="Server SSD Clone", Part_ID="disk3s2"
  Diskutil mountDisk /dev/$Part_ID
End
```

Somewhere else I did read that it is needed to mount partitions by there UUID and NOT by "NAME" or "IDENTIFIER". With the command `diskutil info /dev/disk3` you get this information but then it's needed to extract the "Volume UUID:" from the result.

I would appreciate any suggestions either to part of my question or to a other way to get it done.

Thank you for your help.
Regards
Thomas

Comment: What are the results of the following- `diskutil list external physical` ? I suspect that the results are the same as above.

Comment: Yep, that's true. I could also just type `diskutil list external` to get the same result. Still I need to filter-out rows like `GUID_partition_scheme`, `EFI`, `Apple_Boot`, ... and put it into a loop to mount only the relevant partitions.

Comment: The mounting process is normally handled by the `diskarbitrationd` daemon, which gets notified of newly attached devices, decides which volumes to mount, and mounts them. There might be a way to fake a new device notification and get it to do its usual mount process on an already-attached device, but I don't know how.